# Is is any way to hide/disable the close button of a pop-up window being opened using Javascript window.open()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

- Is is any way to hide/disable the close button of a pop-up window
  being opened using Javascript window.open() ?

Comment: That close button is of browser. You can not hide that. You can use any custom popup for you task.

Comment: If you could do that, think of how many porn popups would do it and prevent you from closing the window.  That would make browsing almost ridiculous.  No, not almost.  It would be ridiculous.  Be grateful that you can't.

Comment: @MystereMan I am yet to encounter _one_ (blocked) porn popup. Which sites are you browsing?

Comment: @JanDvorak - I was using it as an example, since many people are familiar with them.  Insert whatever annoying popup you like instead.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot hide the close button of  a pop-up window.
If you want that sort of control, don't use a window.

Create a dialog winow using [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

This you can style as you want, and the content you show in window.open you can present to the user in an iframe inside the dialog.